# How to implement concurrency if a single row update is based on multiple rows state

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

I need to update a single row in a table. The update, however, is based on the state of several other rows in the same Table. In other words: in business logic every row depends on neighboring rows.

Simplified algorithm is as follows:

1. Select one particular row in a Table that has to be updated,
2. Select several rows from the same Table, which will be used for the 1. update validation
3. Validate
4. Update only the row from 1.

This poses a concurrency problem where if some rows from 2. are updated in the mean time by other user, the row from 1. is still going to be updated, as there is no concurrency check on "read-only" rows.

I figured out to just update all rows despite only one is actually being changed. But maybe there is another, more elegant way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Much easier in pure SQL. You can use a `UPDLOCK` hint on the rows you are reading. Consider writing a stored procedure to do this, and just passing it parameters

Comment: This is indeed helpful. Thank You!